# Как оставить только один цветовой канал в Bitmap?

Tags: android, java

Есть картинка маленькая, надо после клика по ней сделать её синей, отсекая остальные цветные каналы (но не трогая альфу). Как бы это попроще сделать? Можно ли стандартным каким фильтром?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если картинка действительно маленькая (суммарной площадью не более 10^6 пикселей), то можно с помощью класса Bitmap удалить из каждого пикселя R и G каналы, оставив только B:

```
...
for(int y=0; y<bmpHeight; y++)
for(int x=0; x<bmpWidth; x++)
{
   myBitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.blue(myBitmap.getPixel(x,y))); 
}
...
```

Comment: Картинка маленькая - 360 пикселов всего. Иконка

Comment: В таком случае можно не искать более быстрого алгоритма фильтрации цветового канала изображения. Хотя и приведенный выше способ довольно медлителен.

Comment: Хмм

    Bitmap getBlueBitmap (Bitmap source){
        int bmpHeight = source.getHeight();
        int bmpWidth = source.getWidth();
        Bitmap answer = source;
        for(int y=0; y<bmpHeight; y++)
            for(int x=0; x<bmpWidth; x++)
            {
                answer.setPixel(x, y, Color.blue(source.getPixel(x, y)));
            }
        return answer;
    }

Что-то ругается на строку

    answer.setPixel(x, y, Color.blue(source.getPixel(x, y)));

Мол, java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: Проблема кроется где-то в ваших Bitmap`ах. Например, что у вас в source?
В курсе ли вы, что answer и source - это один и тот же объект( ссылаются на одну область памяти )?  

Плюс, прочитайте описание исключения:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html

Comment: Исправил дело так

     Bitmap getBlueBitmap (Bitmap source){
     int Height = source.getHeight();
     int Width = source.getWidth();
     Bitmap answer = Bitmap.createBitmap(Width , Height , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     int[] srcPixels = new int[Width * Height ];
     source.getPixels(srcPixels, 0, Width, 0, 0, Width, Height );
     int[] destPixels = new int[Width * Height ];
     for (int i = 0; i < srcPixels.length; i++) {
         destPixels[i] = (srcPixels[i] & 0xff0000ff);
     }
     answer.setPixels(destPixels, 0, Width , 0, 0, Width , Height );
     return answer;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Это не подойдет?

[Рисование. ColorFilter, ColorMatrix](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/353-urok-153-risovanie-colorfilter-colormatrix.html)